# AVSpeechSynthesizer read text just one time and then doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech

I have a problem with **AVSpeechSynthesizer**, this read the text just one time and then doesn't work anymore.

Currently I'm using the [AVSpeechSynthesizerFacade class](https://github.com/dale-moore/iOSTextToSpeech/blob/master/AVSpeechSynthesizerFacade.h) to do it.

I have a map with some points. If I tap on a pin, I see the details view with the text. I start the synthesizer in a singleton class in my project, so it is always the same.

```
+ (WikipediaConnectionManager*)sharedmanager {
    static WikipediaConnectionManager* sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [WikipediaConnectionManager new];
        NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

        NSString* language = [locale localeIdentifier];

        sharedManager.language = [language substringToIndex:2];
        sharedManager.synthetizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizerFacade alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedManager;
}
```

I call the method `speakText` when I tap on play start to speak.

```
-(IBAction)didTapPlayButton:(id)sender{

    WikipediaConnectionManager* sharedManager = [WikipediaConnectionManager sharedmanager];

    if(self.playCount == 0){

        [sharedManager.synthetizer speakText:self.textView.text];

        self.playCount = self.playCount + 1;
        [self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pausa.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.play = YES;
    }
    else{
        if(self.play == NO){
            BOOL continueSpeaking = [sharedManager.synthetizer continueSpeak];

            if (continueSpeaking == NO) {

               [sharedManager.synthetizer speakText:self.textView.text];
            }
            self.play = YES;
            [self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pausa.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else{
            [sharedManager.synthetizer pause];
            self.play = NO;
            [self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

When I come back to the map and I come back again in the details view, in another pin or the same doesn't matter, the synthesizer doesn't read the text.

Comment: Maybe because you never decrement self.playCount so it is never zero again?

Comment: Because I need it to start play first time

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53626384/9224215) could help.