# AVSpeechSynthesizer is not working After use one time

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech

I'm using AVSpeechSynthesizer for voice out some text data, it'll work for first time but it didn't work after that.

I'm getting below messages.

**Error:-**

> AppName[859:101035] [AXTTSCommon] Failure starting audio queue alp!
>   2018-10-26 18:06:53.253536+0530 AppName[859:101035] [AXTTSCommon]
>   _BeginSpeaking: couldn't begin playback

Below i share my code.

```
 let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

 fileprivate func speakText(voiceOutdata: String )
 {
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: voiceOutdata)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    synth.speak(utterance)
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the `AVAudioSession` for performing such tasks. Here is my working code. Hope this helps.

```
func speakText(voiceOutdata: String ) {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
    }

    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: voiceOutdata)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synth.speak(utterance)

    defer {
        disableAVSession()
    }
}

private func disableAVSession() {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("audioSession properties weren't disable.")
    }
}
```

Comment: can I get same code in Objective-C ??? coz I am also having same issue & my code is in Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

for me the problem was my `speaker volume` was off and it was also in the `vibration mode`

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
 fileprivate func speakText(voiceOutdata: String ){
    synthesizer.stopSpeakingAtBoundary(.Immediate)
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: voiceOutdata)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    synthesizer.speakUtterance(utterance)
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

its working for me:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
} catch {
    print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
}
```